# How to pass DBNull when convert data type of item in DataTable: Object can't cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#

I found almost case relate with SQL connection and SQLReader.

The problem is: when looping to all items in DataTable.

I must convert row `r["Age"]` and `r["Numphone"]` to double type.

Seem have any item `null`.

I tried for loop all rows to set `field1 = ""`.

```
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        var field1 = r[dc].ToString();
        if (field1 == null)
            field1 = "";
    }
```

But my code not working.

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            var field1 = r[dc].ToString();
            if (field1 == null)
                field1 = "";
        }

        double[] inforNum = { Convert.ToDouble(r["Age"]), Convert.ToDouble(r["Numphone"]) };
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `ToString()` on it without check for `null` so it will fail, you should be checking for `null` first then call `ToString()` like:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    var field1 = r[dc]!=null ? r[dc].ToString() : "";
}
```

the same you need to do for the other line of code:

```
var age = r["Age"] !=null ? Convert.ToDouble(r["Age"]) : 0;
var numPhone = r["Numphone"] !=null ? Convert.ToDouble(r["Numphone"]) : 0;

double[] inforNum = new[]{ age , numPhone };
```

Comment: I think DataColumn `dc` include `r["Age"]` and `r["Numphone"]. Because I was loop all DataColumns in DataTable `dt`. But the problem is: other columns don't need convert to Double type.

Comment: I have `r["A0_2"]` have valued `""` but it detects is have values and I can't `Convert.ToDouble` for it rows. You can see image for more information: http://imgur.com/Z9GwKJG

Comment: there is no value in it

Comment: I change to: `var age = r["Age"].ToString() != "" ? Convert.ToDouble(r["Age"]) : 0;` and it working.

Comment: @VănLộc better would be to use ``string.IsNullOrEmpty(r["Age"])``

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataRow.IsNull` or even better `DataRow.Field` which supports nullable types:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    double? age = row.Field<double?>("Age");
    double? numphone = row.Field<double?>("Numphone");
    if(age.HasValue && numphone.HasValue)
    {
         double[] inforNum = { age.Value, numphone.Value };
    }
}
```

You should not use `ToString` to convert the double to a string first and then `Convert.ToDouble` to convert it back to a double. That's not efficient and could cause conversion issues. Instead simply cast it to the correct type which seems to be a `double`.

Also, don't use exceptions to control program flow and don't use empty cacth blocks.

Comment: i like your solution, that's more better and clean (y) but it would'nt create array if one of them is null